# Image in navigation drawer not visible

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've noticed that image in navigation drawer not showing up. I was able to see it before. This is my nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What may cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
```

Comment: Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'marginTop' in package 'android'

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Try it out now.